# Proving that if $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence and that if every convergent subsequence of $(a_n)$ converges to $a $, then $(a_n)$ converges to $a$.

Tags: real-analysis

The proof that I found goes roughly like this : using the negation of the statement of convergence, it is possible to build a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ that never enters the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $V_\epsilon(a)$. Then, since $(a_n)$ is bounded, this implies that $(a_{n_k})$ is also bounded and we can apply the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem to it to obtain a subsequence of $(a_{n_k})$ which is also a subsequence of $(a_n)$. Since it is a subsequence of $(a_n)$, it is supposed to converge but since it is a subsequence of $(a_{n_k})$, it never enters the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $a$ and thus does not converge to $a$. This completes the proof.

My question is why should we use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem to produce a subsequence that never enters the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $a$ when we already constructed one namely $(a_{n_k})$. Should $(a_{n_k})$ not already be a subsequence of $(a_n)$ that does not converge to $a$ (and hence the proof is completed ?) ? I know there is a logical flaw in the argument (since the fact that $(a_n)$ was bounded was not used) but I cannot find it.

Comment: Your question as stated is trivial: $\{a_n\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$, so it converges to $a$. There's nothing to prove.

Comment: @John OP surely meant to say "if $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence and that if every **convergent** subsequence of $(a_n)$ converges to $a $, then $(a_n)$ converges to $a$."

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Yes this is what I meant.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM You may be right. Still, John's comment is very appropriate: If OP meant to say what he did, then this is a lesson: if you improperly ask questions, the answers may drastically change.

Comment: Do you know what limsup and liminf are?

Comment: I know what the supremum and infimum are but I don't know what limsup and liminf mean.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM : Actually I am guessing "every subsequence has a further subsequence converging to $a$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you got the rationale of the proof wrong.

Firstly, one assumes that $(a_n)$ does not converge. This yields the existence of some $\epsilon$ such that $\forall N\in \mathbb N$, there is some $n\geq N$ such that $a_n \notin V_{\epsilon}(a)$. This allows you to build a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $\forall k, a_{n_k}\notin V_{\epsilon}(a)$.

Now, since $a_{n_k}$ is bounded, it has a convergence subsequence, say $b_n$, and $b_n$ is therefore a convergent subsequence of $a_{n_k}$, but also a convergent subsequence of $a_n$. Hence $b_n$ converges to $a$. But that is a contradiction, since $b_n$ is a subsequence of $a_{n_k}$.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, you initially have a subsequence which never enters the $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $a$, but you do not know that the subsequence converges converges. So the proof uses boundedness and Bolzano-Weierstrass to construct a convergent subsequence which never enters the $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $a$. Once you have such a convergent subsequence you can show that the limit is not $a$.

Comment: Yes, I have realised the flaw in my reasoning. I was wrongly assuming that  every subsequence was supposed to be convergent. Thank you.

Comment: @P.Munbodh In fact every subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent (e.g. it satisfies the Cauchy condition, once this is established). It seems so obvious sometimes that it is hard to see where it is being assumed.

Comment: Exactly and here, I assumed it was true while actually trying to prove the convergence of $(a_n)$. I made a circular reasoning.